# Are the kind of mutations different in an antibiotic setting than they are in a non antibiotic setting?

Tags: mutations, antibiotic-resistance

Hy everyone!

I'm looking for experiments that deal with the kind of mutations that arise in antibiotic environment, as opposed to non antibiotic environment. As far as I understand, AB (anti biotic) doesn't change the kind of mutations that arise, it only gives advantage to the lineage that's already resistant. However I cant find an experiment that deals with this directly. What google brings up is only the Lederman experiment, however I can't find an experiment that deals with the aftermath.

What I'm imagining is this:

- we create a replica from bacteria and put one of them in AB environment (or preferably many replicas from both groups
- at every generation (or at least at certain times) we check the genetical makeup of bacteria in both of the AB and non-AB populations

Will the groups of bacteria at the same place (the "same" lineages) have almost the same genetical makeup with a comparable genetic drift? Or will there some specific mutations arise repeatedly in the AB group as opposed a non selective environment? I understand this can only be tested up to a few generations because after a while we are only testing selection and not mutation itself. However Im curious if there is such an experiment out there and if there isn't, why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is essentially the same as the Luria-Delbrück experiment. They were interested more in phage resistance than antibiotics, but there is no theoretical difference. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luria%E2%80%93Delbr%C3%BCck_experiment) Similar work has been done in antibiotics, even earlier it seems, though not so famous. A recent theoretical treatment with many relevant citations is here: https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1007930

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sorry for responding so late. Maybe I'm misunderstanding but it seems to me that the Luria Delbruck experiment deals with preexisting variations, before they are introduced to the virus. What I'm curious about is whether once a line of bacteria is introduced to the environment with the virus and it survives, will it start to develop a different group of mutations compared to a line that wasn't introduced to the virus? Maybe it is a pointless test, as the underlying mechanism is supposed to be the same as the L-D experiment, but I'm curious if it has been carried out.